# touchpad cursor laggy

Tags: touchpad

yesterday, I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my Lenovo Ideapad Gaming 3 but the touchpad isn't working properly. Whenever I use it, it's moving laggy and slowy. When I use an external mouse, everything is fine. How can I solve this problem?